# Thailand visa with a short visit to Cambodia

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, thailand, cambodia, repeat-visits

We are planning a December trip to Singapore and from there to Thailand. I read that the 15-day VOA applies to us, being citizens of one of those EU countries.

We will arrive in Bangkok, stay 4-5 days, go to Cambodia for the next 2-3 days and back to Bangkok/Krabi for about a week more, then fly home. All border crossings are planned to be done by air, and reserved before the trip starts. Same for accommodations.

The interval when we first enter Thailand and when we exit it the last time will be 16-18 days, which is over this 15-day limit period.

- In my understanding, this will require 2 VOAs, on the first arrival and another one on the second one from Cambodia. Is this correct?
- Does this interval (16-18 days) matter at all? Does the second VOA reset this day counter considering we leave for 2-3 days and it's not just a visa run?
- Is this legally acceptable? Could we have some issues with this itinerary?

Answer (score 3):

You would indeed two VoAs each, and that would be fine as far as Immigration is concerned. As long as you leave within the allowed time, Thai Immigration won't care.

However, why bother? Just do all your Thailand visits on your first VoA, then fly to Cambodia and back: you can transfer in BKK on your way back home, without needing a second VoA, if you use one of the airlines that fly to Cambodia from BKK (assuming your flight home is from BKK too, of course, since you say you're from the EU, and there's no flight from DMK to the EU).

You'll save quite a bit of money, and time, applying for only one VoA each... As you'll see, the VoA facility in BKK can be a fine circus if you arrive around the same time as a flight from India or China...